# why use final as modifier when we have private in method classes

Tags: class, oop, private, final

Let's consider that we have a method which has been declared as below:

```
final private method myMethod() {

}
```

Why should we use `final` when we have `private` as a modifier. What exactly is the purpose of final here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final` prevents a method from being overriding in any subclass. But it is still accessible from other classes.

`private` makes a method inaccessible from any other class.

So make a method `final` when you want to make sure that no child class overrides(changes the implementation) this method.

Make it `private` when you want that no other class should be able to use it directly.